# HTML & CSS issue for showing UI

Tags: html, css

here is my html and css as follows. i just can not understand why `city & state` is showing differently. in case of city & state label comes & input type come side by side but i want they should stay on form one after one like other input.

### here is my html

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(241, 242, 242); height: auto; width: auto;" id="Register">
    <fieldset>


<legend>información sobre el transporte</legend>

                    <br>
                    <span id="lblBillShip" name="lblBillShip">Marque si misma que la dirección de facturación</span>
                    <span style="margin-left:330px; margin-top:-21px; display:block;" class="noEnterSubmit"><input type="checkbox" name="chkBillShipSame" id="chkBillShipSame"></span><br><br>

                    <span id="lblAdd1" name="lblAdd1">Dirección 1</span>
                    <input type="text" class="noEnterSubmit" id="txtAdd1" name="txtAdd1"><br><br>

                    <span id="lblAdd2" name="lblAdd2">Dirección 2</span>
                    <input type="text" class="noEnterSubmit" id="txtAdd2" name="txtAdd2"><br><br>

                    <span id="lblCity" name="lblCity">City</span>
                    <input type="text" class="noEnterSubmit" id="txtCity" name="txtCity"><br><br>

                    <span id="lblState" name="lblState">State</span>
                    <input type="text" class="noEnterSubmit" id="txtState" name="txtState"><br><br>
                    <br><br>

                    <span id="lblPostCode" name="lblPostCode">PostCode</span>
                    <input type="text" class="noEnterSubmit" id="txtPostCode" name="txtPostCode"><br><br><br>

                </fieldset>
             </div>
```

### and CSS

```
#main1 { width:560px; margin: 0px auto; padding:40px 20px 20px; background-color:#FFFFFF; top:50px;}
    legend { font-size:18px; margin:0px; padding:10px 0px; color:#2F9934; font-weight:bold;}
    fieldset { border-style: none;
            border-color: inherit;
            border-width: medium;
            width:322px;
            margin-left:30px;
        }
    #overlay {
          position: fixed;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          z-index: 1000000;
          color:Blue;
          background: url('/images/busy.gif');
          background-repeat:no-repeat;
          background-position:600px 390px;
          text-align:center;
        }
    #Register  label { display:block; margin:15px 0 5px;}
    #Register  input[type=text], input[type=password] { width:300px; }
    #Register input[type=checkbox] {padding-top:5px;}
    #Register  select {width:175px; height:19px; padding-top:5px;}
```

[here is jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/A8dux/)

please guide me what i need to change as a result label & text boxes should stay on form one after one like other input. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of how much you are able to display in one line, and as the label "City" and State" are shorter than the other labels these will fit in one line and not break.
To force a line-break after your labels you could add something like this to your stylesheet:

```
#Register  span { 
    display:block; 
}
```

Comment: This is correct. You might want to add that span's are naturally *inline* elements that would normally be placed next to eachother if the space is available.

Answer (score 1):

If you add CSS to the `span` elements `float:left`. This resolves the issue

```
#Register span{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8dux/1/)

Comment: I don't understand why this gets an up vote. The solution you give only accidentally solves the problem. Floating the element would normally cause them to be displayed next to eachother. That's not what the OP wants. It's your luck that `float:left;` automatically makes the element a block element, which solves the issue of the OP. It seems that you don't understand the basics of CSS yourself, but just got lucky.

Answer (score 1):

```
   #Register span {
    display:block;
    }
```

Will solve the issue.

You should be using `label` instead of `span` though.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/wq3Xs/)